# How do I dynamically load HTML and insert into my web page with Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I dynamically load a snippet of HTML and insert it into my web page? I am using Dart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Glad you asked! Using Dart for this task isn't much different than JavaScript, except you get typing, code completion, and a slick editing experience.

First, create the snippet.html:

```html
<p>This is the snippet</p>
```

Next, create the application. Notice the use of XMLHttpRequest to request the snippet. Also, use `new Element.html(string)` to create a block of HTML from a string.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var div = querySelector('#insert-here');
  HttpRequest.getString("snippet.html").then((resp) {
    div.append(new Element.html(resp));
  });
}
```

Finally, here's the host HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>dynamicdiv</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>dynamicdiv</h1>
    <div id="insert-here"></div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="dynamicdiv.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...and what appears to be a slick solution.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is now HttpRequest

Comment: huh? You asked the question and then say to yourself `Glad you asked!` Though rather strange, the answer you gave to yourself was helpful.

Comment: Hi @FrançoisWahl it turns out that the "ask and answer yourself" is acceptable to Stack Overflow. Sometimes I do this when I find a gem that I want to share with others. :)

Comment: @sethladd: I know it's acceptable I was just a little confused that you asked it and answered it at the same time. I like the idea and understand why you did it now. I wish SO would have a wiki feature for sharing good information like this instead.

Answer (score 3):

main.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

DivElement div = querySelector('div');

main() async {
  String template = await HttpRequest.getString("template.html");
  div.setInnerHtml(template, treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);
}
```

template.html:

```
<h1>Hello world.</h1>

Check my bird... <em>it flies</em> !
<img src="https://www.dartlang.org/logos/dart-bird.svg">
```

For the full example, that runs out of the box, see:

https://gist.github.com/kasperpeulen/536b021ac1cf397d4e6d

Note that you need 1.12 to get `NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted` working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example.

https://jsfiddle.net/kofwe39d/ (JS compiled from Dart source code.)

`web/main.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:virtual_dom/components/component.dart';
import 'package:virtual_dom/features/state.dart';
import 'package:virtual_dom/helpers/h.dart';
import 'package:virtual_dom/helpers/mount.dart';
import 'package:virtual_dom/helpers/styles.dart';
import 'package:virtual_dom/helpers/vhtml.dart';

void main() {
  final app = document.getElementById('app')!;
  mount(app, _App());
}

class _App extends Component {
  @override
  Object render() {
    final timer = State.get('timer', () => 3);
    final setTimer = State.set<int>('timer');
    if (timer > 0) {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        setTimer(timer - 1);
      });
    }

    final html = timer > 0
        ? ''
        : '''
Hello, <strong>World!</strong>
''';

    final style = styles({'padding': '6px'});
    return h('div', {
      'style': style
    }, [
      if (timer > 0) '$timer sec',
      h('p', 'Your html:'),
      vHtml('div', html),
    ]);
  }
}
```

`web/index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%; font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:1.5">
  <div id="app" style="height: 100%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```